# How do I achieve equal-height menu list items?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I tried using flex and still the items does not stretch  maximum height of items.

```css
ul.sub-menu-nav {
    padding:0px;
    height:100%;
    -ms-box-orient: horizontal;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-align-items: stretch; 
    align-items: stretch;

    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    margin:0px;
}
 li.sub-menu-top {
    height:100%;
}
```

```html
<ul class="sub-menu-nav">
    <li class="sub-menu-top" data-parent="0" data-id="3">
        <h3><a href="#">Advertising</a></h3>
        <ul class="sub-sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Departments</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Previous Commercials</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Current Commercials</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TechAnim</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="sub-menu-top" data-id="16" data-parent="3">
        <h3><a href="#">Training</a></h3>
        <ul class="sub-sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Academy</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">All Tutorials</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Pipeline</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Digital Tutors</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Intranet</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Training</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Tutorials</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Feedback</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

[JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/Bl_praveen2004/1zskxj24/)

Plausible table-row and table-cell was also not showing equal heights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to make the gray left borders the same height? Here's my solution:

```css
ul.sub-menu-nav {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
}

li.sub-menu-top {
  padding: 0px 20px;
  border-left: 1px gray solid;
}

ul.sub-sub-menu {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
}

ul.sub-sub-menu li {
  padding: 4px 20px;
}

ul.sub-sub-menu li a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="sub-menu-nav">
  <li class="sub-menu-top">
    <h3><a href="#">Advertising</a></h3>
    <ul class="sub-sub-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Departments</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Previous Commercials</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Current Commercials</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">TechAnim</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="sub-menu-top">
    <h3><a href="#">Training</a></h3>
    <ul class="sub-sub-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Academy</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">All Tutorials</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Pipeline</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Digital Tutors</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Intranet</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Training</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tutorials</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Feedback</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks,let me check If it works. what is difference here? I have also used display :flex in my question. why the border did not stretch the whole height

Comment: In your code, remove the CSS block: `li.sub-menu-top { height:100%; }`

Comment: I came to know waht is the problem I have give the li height 100%. it was because off this. I have updated the fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/Bl_praveen2004/1zskxj24/1/ . Thanks, I got it